# Error: find argument list too long and -maxdepth 0 is not helping, directory contains many files

Tags: find, ls, delete

I'm trying to delete image cache files older then 100 days via command

`find /mnt/data/cache/*.jpg -maxdepth 0  -mtime +100  -type f -ls -delete`

but the thing is **/mnt/data/cache/** contain large amount of files and i'm getting as error

> bash: /usr/bin/find: Argument list too long

**there is no subdirectories in /mnt/data/cache/**. All files in that /mnt/data/cache/ folder and standard **-maxdepth 0** solution is not helping

So is there any way to do find by some portions or offset limits ?
or is there some alternative command by which i can delete files in directory older then 100 days ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find /mnt/data/cache/*.jpg ...
```

will expand to

```
find /mnt/data/cache/1.jpg /mnt/data/cache/2.jpg /mnt/data/cache/3.jpg ...
```

If you have too many file, this cause error you've seen.

If there is no subdir, you can skip `-maxdepth 0` and `-type f`

what you want is

```
find /mnt/data/cache/ -mtime +100 -name \*.jpg -ls -delete
```

a final word, if you append `> /dev/null`, just drop `-ls`

Comment: Yes working thank you